# Why covering index is not used in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, indexing, postgresql-9.6

I have a simple testing table `GTable(id int, groupby int, orderby int, padding varchar(1000))`. I have this table in SQL Server 2016, PostgreSQL 9.6.1 and Oracle 12c with almost the same data. Bellow, you can see the script used to create the table in PostgreSQL.

**PostgreSQL data**

```
CREATE TABLE GTable (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    groupby INT NOT NULL,
    orderby INT NOT NULL,
    padding VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

INSERT
INTO    GTable
SELECT  s, 
        s % 100, 
        s % 10000, 
        RPAD('Value ' || s || ' ' , 500, '*')
FROM    generate_series(1, 100000) s;
```

I have created index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_gtable_groupby_orderby ON gtable(groupby, orderby);
```

and run the following query

```
SELECT groupby, max(orderby) gmax
FROM gtable
GROUP BY groupby;
```

Whereas Oracle and SQL Server uses the index to process the query (using a sequential scan), the PostgreSQL does not. Never. I have tried to alter the selectivity, but without success. Here is the PostgreSQL explain (analyze, buffers)

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=8643.00..8643.10 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=54.906..54.907 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: groupby"
"  Buffers: shared hit=4410 read=2733"
"  ->  Seq Scan on gtable  (cost=0.00..8143.00 rows=100000 width=8) (actual time=0.077..32.065 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=4410 read=2733"
"Planning time: 0.096 ms"
"Execution time: 54.955 ms"
```

**Question**

Therefore, why PostgreSQL is not using the index for the query? Is there chance that under a different data distribution the index is used?

**Oracle**

I add Oracle creation script if somebody like to try it

```
CREATE TABLE gtable (id NOT NULL, groupby NOT NULL, orderby NOT NULL, padding NOT NULL)
AS
SELECT  level, 
        mod(level, 100), 
        mod(level * 7 , 10000),
        CAST(RPAD('Value ' || level || ' ', 500, '*') AS VARCHAR2(500))
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
level <= 1000000;
```

**EDIT**

I have forced PostgreSQL to avoid heap scan as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested (thank you) and I get the following query plan

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=17415.29..17415.39 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=59.014..59.016 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: groupby"
"  Buffers: shared hit=14561"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on gtable  (cost=1629.29..16915.29 rows=100000 width=8) (actual time=10.396..36.956 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=14286"
"        Buffers: shared hit=14561"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_gtable_orderby_groupby  (cost=0.00..1604.29 rows=100000 width=0) (actual time=7.975..7.975 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=275"
"Planning time: 0.127 ms"
"Execution time: 59.260 ms"
```

He uses the index now, however, the `gtable` is accessed anyway. I do not understand why he still accesses the `gtable` even though all data necessary for the result are in the index. Does PostgreSQL have a problem to use indexes with more than one attribute?

Comment: What's the output of `EXPLAIN` for that query?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan as plain [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added

Comment: Did you `analyze` the table after creating the index?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure, I have tried hundred times to change the PostgreSQL behavior. Actually, I was struggling with Oracle as well, however, in the case of Oracle the padding attribute makes a difference, in the case of PostgreSQL it does not.

Comment: On my computer (with a SSD) the [Seq Scan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/W3cT)  is nearly twice as fast as the [Index Only Scan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/LyMm) - so the Seq Scan seems to be the right choice

Comment: Postgres seems to prefer an index on `gtable(orderby, groupby)`: https://explain.depesz.com/s/NS25

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my PostgreSQL is not using even the `gtable(orderby, groupby)` index. Would you be so kind and elaborated your measurements in an answer? I have no idea how you force him to use index scan (even though it is not efficient for him).

Comment: `set enable_seqscan=off;`